# NgRx Load page related content subscription free

Tags: ngrx

The following sends an http request when I go to a specific page, after checking if it was already loaded (a flag I add to the state after they are loaded).
Is there a better way, possibly a subscription free way, to do it?
Maybe some hook on the router-store, some Effect that allows me to check "state" and "route" and in case dispatch the action?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.pageContentSubscription = this.store.select(fromPageContentReducers.getPageContentLoaded)
    .subscribe(loaded => {
      if (!loaded) {
        this.store.dispatch(new pageContentAction.Load());
      }
    });
  this.pageContentSubscription!.unsubscribe();
}
```

Also this won't work with real content loaded asynchronously as it will be unsubscribed before receiving the content.

However if I move the unsubscribe to `ngOnDestroy` instead, the content will get loaded again when logging off from that page, as I run a pageContent.Clear() action that will restore its initial state including the "loaded" flag listening from the "auth.LOGOUT" action.

```
@Effect()
clearPageContent$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(auth.LOGOUT)
  .map(() => new pageContent.Clear());
```

So what I will have with the `unsubscribe` in the `ngOnDestroy` is as follows:
 * Loads the page content
 * User logs off
 * Transactions are cleared, state of "loaded" is restore to false, but
still listening to the "loaded" condition which will trigger the loading of the content once again
 * Begins process of redirecting the user outside of the guarded page
 * PageContent unsubscribed too late

How should I fix this?